# Variable SQL query in Excel

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, excel

I am looking to create a query in excel that queries to find where a row matches the value that is in a colummn. select a few certain columns.

So, I have data in the form

```
668406  
668406-1    
668406-2    
670589  
671259  
671259-1    
671259-2    
671261  
671261-1
```

what I want is to build a query that says

```
SELECT     JobHeaderID, Job,ProofApproved,SleeveLabel, MasterLabel
FROM         JobHeader
WHERE   JobHeader.Job = '668406'
or  JobHeader.Job = '668406-1'
or  JobHeader.Job = '668406-2'
or  JobHeader.Job = '670589'
or  JobHeader.Job = '671259'
or  JobHeader.Job = '671259-1'
or  JobHeader.Job = '671259-2'
or  JobHeader.Job = '671261'
or  JobHeader.Job = '671261-1'
```

[image: TableSameple]

I can  build a query and select the whole tables worth of records, or one or two records when I manually tell it to match those jobs, but I want it to request all of these at once, not me manually typing each one in.

If there was an SQL function, I could just call

```
=SQLQuery(SQLServer,CONCATENATE("SELECT JobHeaderID, Job,ProofApproved,SleeveLabel, MasterLabel
FROM         JobHeader
WHERE   JobHeader.Job = '",C3,"'"))`
```

or something like that and fill my approved column with the current status of whether they are approved or not. If I get this working well, I'll be extended it to two or three more columns as well.  How can I make the Approved column reflect the status of approvals for the adjacent job's status in the SQL server.

**EDIT:** I have no problem building the query, whether it is just for on value or for the whole range at once. I just dont know how to make a query from a Cell or a macro, only importing a selection one time as a SQL data source or using microsoft query to choose values (even all the values) but no way to refernce current values in these queries, I have to key them in by hand. If someone can help me to make an SQLSquery function like I showed above then I'm set, otherwise: I do not need help constructing a query unless you can help me referencing a changing object from inside one of the types of sources I listed above.

Answer (score 0):

In sql server you could do something like

```
SELECT     JobHeaderID, Job,ProofApproved,SleeveLabel, MasterLabel
FROM         JobHeader
WHERE   JobHeader.Job IN (SELECT ColumnName FROM TableName WHERE Your_Condition)
```

OR

```
SELECT     JobHeaderID, Job,ProofApproved,SleeveLabel, MasterLabel
FROM         JobHeader
WHERE   JobHeader.Job IN ('Value1','Value2','Value3',.....)
```

Comment: right, but my condition is that it matches the value in C3. You're just restating my problem without a solution. I know how to write the query, I just don't know how to get excel to run a query that will match all values from C2:C103 for example. and then let me just extend it down through CXX when I get that far. Also I'm not in the SQL server, I'm in an excel file.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to solve this problem in a few steps:

1. Get the range of values to use
2. Translate this range into a string that SQL supports
3. Use this string in the SQL query.

So, you could do this by:

Step 1 and 2:

```
For Each currentCell in Range("C2:C100")

  -- First, check if the last cell has been reached. 
  --If so, don't add the trailing comma
  If (currentCell <> Range("C100") then
    inQueryString = inQueryString & "'" & currentCell.value & "'"
  Else
    inQueryString = inQueryString & "'" & currentCell.value & "',"
  End If
Next
```

Then, the inQueryString would contain a list of values that you can use directly in the SQL query.

```
=SQLQuery(SQLServer,CONCATENATE(
"SELECT JobHeaderID, Job,ProofApproved,SleeveLabel, MasterLabel
FROM         JobHeader
WHERE   JobHeader.Job IN (",inQueryString,")"))
```

Assuming your range is C2:C100 and the last cell is C100.
Hope this helps

Comment: thats a great way to build the query, but actually making the query is the problem. There is no SQLQuery function, I don't know how to make it your query is useless without the mean to make the squery to the server.

Comment: Okay, I edited my question showing how I can handle query making, my problem now is how do i Make (execute) the query to the server. I used the example of an SQLQuery function, but that was a hypothetical, I dont have or know how to make an SQLQuery function.